# Check input[type=checkbox] in jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've got the following HTML:

```
<ul id=list>
    <li>
        <input type=checkbox />
        Item 1
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type=checkbox />
        Item 2
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type=checkbox />
        Item 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

And corresponding JavaScript:

```
$('ul').bind('click', function(e) {

    if (e.srcElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        e.srcElement.checked = true;
    }

    return false;
});
    
$('body').bind('click', function() {

    alert('you should see this alert if and only if you did NOT click the list');

})
```

When I click a checkbox, it does not get checked.  I want it to be checked when the user clicks it.

**How do I make it so the checkbox is checked when the user clicks it, but
still cancel the `body` click event handler?**

I've put up a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/ChwAv/2/) as well.

**Edit:** I understand the code is a bit clunky, but it needs to be structured this way for the application, so solutions should stay as close to the original as possible.  That being said, explanations of the observed behavior would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`e.stopPropagation()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) instead of `return false`. The latter also prevents the default action from happening, which is toggling the state of the checkbox.

You should also consider to bind the event handler to the `change` event instead of `click`, the mouse it not the only way to toggle a checkbox. You'd still need to add an additional handler to prevent the `click` event from bubbling up though.

Comment: Interesting; on Chrome it's not possible to uncheck that way. http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/ChwAv/4/

Comment: @pimvdb: That's not because of Chrome... look closer at the event handler's code ;)

Comment: I noticed e.stopPropagatoion() should be the first line in the event function call, any idea why?

Comment: @Bipins: It should not matter... what problem did you find?

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/RnyeP/  bubbles events when that line is at the end of the function , whereas this does not http://jsfiddle.net/adKPj/ when that line is the first line.

Comment: @Bipins: It appears to be a problem in Firefox. In Chrome it works just fine.

Comment: @Bipins: Correction: It fails in Firefox because `e.stopPropagation()` is never executed. In W3C compatible browsers, the property is called `event.target`, not `event.srcElement`. This throws an error in Firefox. With `target`, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RnyeP/2/

Comment: yeah so there it failed, i found out about jquery using event.target for both cases

Answer (score 2):

1. You are binding click to "ul" , you should be binding it to "ul> input"
2. to avoid getting click bubbled you need to cancel bubble using event.stopPropagation()
   I noticed stopPropagation() should be the first thing in the function.

   ```
   $('ul').bind('click', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
          e.target.checked = true;
       }
   });

   $('body').bind('click', function() {

       alert('you should see this alert if and only if you did NOT click the list');
    });
   ```

Comment: i appreciate the feedback, but in the context of my application i need to be binding to 'ul', not 'li'.  i have of course simplified it for the sake of the SO question.

Comment: i want to bind one event to the 'ul' element, and one to the 'body' element.  i do not want to bind to the 'li' element or the 'input' element.  there is a reason, but there is not space to get into it.

Comment: Ya sure, you can bind to ul element only too, if that is what u want. :)

Comment: Aaron, is what i have proposed above not the behavior you want ?

Comment: you can use e.target instead, srcElement and target are same depending on browser, jquery says that it normalizes both to "target" for cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ChwAv/12/) is what you want ?

```
$('ul').bind('click', function(e) {          
    e.stopPropagation();       
});

$('body').bind('click', function() {
    alert('you only see this alert if and only if you did NOT click the list');
})
```

Comment: I guess that would be   e.stopPropagation  .... the even variable of that event handler.

Comment: Actually weirdly i corrected it at almost the same time you left that comment.